# Objections against using javax.crypto directly on Android

Tags: android, encryption

I read about encryption on Android using the Android classes, e.g. here: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/02/data-encryption-on-android-with-jetpack.html.

However AndroidX Security and other classes from `android.security` like `KeyGenParameterSpec` can only be used on API 23 and above.

So I wondered if there are any objections against using `javax.crypto` classes directly on Android e.g. as it's done here: https://mkyong.com/java/java-aes-encryption-and-decryption/

```
public class EncryptorAesGcmPasswordFile {

    private static final String ENCRYPT_ALGO = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
    private static final int TAG_LENGTH_BIT = 128; // must be one of {128, 120, 112, 104, 96}
    private static final int IV_LENGTH_BYTE = 12;
    private static final int SALT_LENGTH_BYTE = 16;

    private static final Charset UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] pText, String password) throws Exception {

        byte[] salt = CryptoUtils.getRandomNonce(SALT_LENGTH_BYTE);

        byte[] iv = CryptoUtils.getRandomNonce(IV_LENGTH_BYTE);

        SecretKey aesKeyFromPassword = CryptoUtils.getAESKeyFromPassword(password.toCharArray(), salt);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPT_ALGO);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKeyFromPassword, new GCMParameterSpec(TAG_LENGTH_BIT, iv));

        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(pText);

        byte[] cipherTextWithIvSalt = ByteBuffer.allocate(iv.length + salt.length + cipherText.length)
                .put(iv)
                .put(salt)
                .put(cipherText)
                .array();

        return cipherTextWithIvSalt;

    }

    // ...
}
```

Are there any security or other issues using pure javax.crypto code on Android?

Comment: I am not aware of any simply for using `javax.crypto` -- after all, even with those Android APIs, you still use `javax.crypto` for most stuff. [There are ways to misuse that API](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/security-crypto-provider-deprecated-in.html). And the actual implementation of it has varied (originally a fork of Bouncy Castle, later replaced by one backed by conscrypt(?)). Part of the push to use the `android.security` APIs is the possibility of hardware-backed keystores, which you can't get from a pure `javax.crypto` approach.